# Group the records and sort groups in itself

Tags: mysql, sql, database, grouping, mysql-5.6

I have 2 columns in my *pricing* table: *car_id* and *price*

I want to

- Group the records with same *car_id*s and sort these groups by *price* in itself. (namely, all records with the same *car_id* must be listed consecutively.)
- I want to sort these groups by minimum price they include.

For example,

```
car_id | price
---------------
1      |   2
1      |   5
2      |   3
2      |   1
2      |   10
3      |   7
3      |   3
3      |   8
```

should be sorted like this:

```
car_id | price
---------------
2      |   1
2      |   3
2      |   10
1      |   2 
1      |   5 
3      |   3 
3      |   7 
3      |   8
```

How can I write a query that performs this operation? I am using MySQL V5.6.

Comment: what if the min `price` is the same accross different `car_id`?

Comment: Actually, doesn't matter. Records with less car_id value can be above in those situations.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a subquery since the 5.6 does not support the window functions.

```
select *, 
  (
    select min(price) 
    from datatab d2
    where d1.car_id = d2.car_id
  ) min_price
from datatab d1
order by min_price, car_id, price
```

[DBFIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9b53e9dfc1252cd5145a3f67ed3572b4)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery that returns the min price for each car_id in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
order by 
  (select min(price) from tablename where car_id = t.car_id), 
  car_id, 
  price
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iaQBFRWpeG8qxpDGKsV3Dr/0).
Or join the table to the subquery that returns all the min prices:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select car_id, min(price) minprice
  from tablename 
  group by car_id
) m on m.car_id = t.car_id
order by 
  m.minprice, 
  t.car_id, 
  t.price
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iaQBFRWpeG8qxpDGKsV3Dr/1).
Results:

```
| car_id | price |
| ------ | ----- |
| 2      | 1     |
| 2      | 3     |
| 2      | 10    |
| 1      | 2     |
| 1      | 5     |
| 3      | 3     |
| 3      | 7     |
| 3      | 8     |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select p.*
from pricing p
order by min(price) over (partition by car_id),
         car_id;
```

The `car_id` handles the case when multiple `car_id`s  have the same minimum price.

In older versions of MySQL, you can do something similar with a subquery:

```
select p.*
from pricing p
order by (select min(p2.price) from pricing p2 where p2.car_id = p.car_id),
         car_id;
```

Comment: One of my friend suggested that solution too but unfortunately window functions are not available in mysql v5.6